# Is there an equivalent to ppp marks for pp3?

Tags: spatstat

I would like to run a mark correlation function on a simple 3d dataset, but it seems like you cannot assign marks with a pp3... Am I missing something or are there other means?

Answer (score 1):

The function `pp3` doesn’t accept a `marks` argument, but you can assign marks to the resulting object:

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- runif(100)
X <- pp3(x, y, z, c(0, 1), c(0,1), c(0,1))
marks(X) <- rnorm(100)
```

This uses the method `marks<-.ppx`. Methods for class `ppx` apply to class `pp3`.

However, mark correlation functions are not yet implemented for `pp3` objects. The help for `markcorr` says that the point pattern must be two-dimensional.